# Приостановить поток

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Есть такая конструкция

```
Thread waitEnter = new Thread(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++)
        {
            DrawField();
            ruleSet.Tick();
        }
    });
waitEnter.Start();

cki = Console.ReadKey();
if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    waitEnter.Abort();
```

В последней строчке хотел вызвать Sleep, но его нет в инталисенсе. Хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку поток(приложение) останавливалось, при еще одном нажатии возобновляло работу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Более безопасный метод, чем Suspend/Resume, которые могут оставить данные неконсистентными, - использовать событие или семафор:

```
var suspend = new ManualResetEvent(true);

Thread waitEnter = new Thread(() =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000; i++) {
        // если событие не в сигнальном состоянии
        // поток приостановится здесь
        suspend.WaitOne(Timeout.Infinite);

        DrawField();
        ruleSet.Tick();
    }
});

waitEnter.Start();

bool working = true;
while (true) {
    var cki = Console.ReadKey();
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
        waitEnter.Abort();
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.Spacebar) {
        if (working) {
            suspend.Reset(); // приостановка на следующей итерации цикла
        } else {
            suspend.Set(); // возобновление
        }
        working ^= true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если уж на то пошло, то и `Thread.Abort` использовать не следует :)

Comment: использовал, что-бы выложить примерный код

Comment: @kvm спасибо за решение

Comment: Только лучше все-таки `ManualResetEventSlim` использовать - оно хоть "холостых" системных вызовов делать не будет.

Comment: +1, но `working ^= true;` совершенно нечитаемо. Лучше, по идее, `working = !working;`.

Answer (score 1):

Наверное, вам нужен был [`Suspend`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.suspend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). А для возобновления - [`Resume`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.resume%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Только осторожнее с этими методами - ваш случай (ручная приостановка/возобновление пользователем) - это, наверное, единственный случай, когда эти методы к месту. Не используйте их для других целей (например, для синхронизации потоков).